# I execute following query but query is not running properly?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I execute following query

```
select sub_category, sum(quantity) from "Recon".fk_starchi group by sub_category
```

how to edit output in postgrsql
the output of above query is

```
  sub_ctegory      sum
                    0
     shoe          1121
     sandle        2101
```

I dont want first row where sum is 0 and sub category is blank space .
what changes should i do in my query .

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/tutorial-select.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your output tells me that you have one or more rows where the subcategory is null. To find them,

```
select *
from "Recon".fk_starchi 
where sub_category is null;
```

To fix that data, you need to either update those rows with a valid subcategory, or delete those rows.

If you don't want to *fix* the data, you can suppress that unwanted row like this.

```
select sub_category, sum(quantity) 
from "Recon".fk_starchi 
where sub_category is not null
group by sub_category;
```

Answer (score 0):

The output means you have a record with empty sub_category and quantity=0 somewhere in the table.

If you want to ignore it you can simply add 'WHERE quantity>0'